# How do I debug my function just using jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I wrote a function to check whether 2 strings are anagrams of each other. Then, I wrote test cases for that function using jasmine. There was something wrong with my checkAnagram function, because of which my jasmine tests failed.

What next? How do I use just jasmine to debug my function?

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/divyanthj/hs6agm4g/3/)

```
var anagrams = {
checkAnagram : function(string1, string2) {
    var that = this;
    var count1 = that.countLetters(string1);
       var count2 = that.countLetters(string2);
       var anagram = true;
       for(var i in count1) {

           if(count2[i] && count1[i]==count2[i]) {
               anagram = true;
           } else {
               anagram = false;
           }
       }
    return anagram;

},
countLetters : function(str) {
    var obj = {};
    for(var char in str) {
        if(!obj[char]) {
            obj[char]=1;
        } else {
            obj[char]++;
        }
    }
    return obj;
   }
  }

describe("Checks if strings are anagrams of each other", function(){
    it("Anagram checker works", function(){
       expect(anagrams.checkAnagram("god","dog")).toEqual(true);
       expect(anagrams.checkAnagram("god","doge")).toEqual(false);
    });

});
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Jasmine specifically - but the function is failing because `doge` has more letters than `god`, yet the iterator only iterates for `god`'s letters. If you were to make a check confirming that both inputs had the same length, before the `for` loop you'd be good to go.

Comment: I agree with HPierce. Length should be your first check.

Comment: After doing only 5 minutes of research (please correct me if I'm wrong) it looks like Jasmine.js isn't intended for debugging _per se_ - just testing. All the debugging is done using conventional debugging techniques and writing a debugging guide is pretty far outside the scope of a good SO question.

Comment: Thanks. I know it, but this is about learning to use jasmine. I apologize if I misrepresented the goal of this question.

I'm wondering if it's possible to eliminate the need to insert console logs and breakpoints, with jasmine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are use karma-runner, it is not tied to angular even though it is from the angular team, you can have chrome run the jasmine test in debug mode. 
With karam running open the karma debug window by clicking the debug button on the chrome window and then open the developer tools.
In the sources you should be able to see the jasmine spec. This may vary on your setup, I see it under base/src. Do your breakpoints and reload the page. And Bobs your auntie.